# C++ : user defined Explicit type conversion function error

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading, user-defined-types, ambiguity

Here is how the code looks:

```
using namespace std;
class dummy{
public:
    int x;
    explicit dummy(int x = 0) : x{ this->x = x } {}; //explicit has no effect here
};

class myClass {
public:
    operator int(); //<---problematic conversion
    explicit operator dummy();

};

myClass::operator int() {
    return 10;
}

myClass::operator dummy(){
    return dummy(9);
}

int main() {
    myClass mc1; 
    dummy val = (dummy)mc1;
    cout << "mc1 int cast: " << mc1 << endl; 
    cout << "val.x: :" << val.x << endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using ms vs compiler here and getting c2440 (type cast error). To my understanding, I'm not doing anything wrong syntax-wise. The problem here is that it works fine if I remove the implicit conversion: `operator int()` and its respective function out of the code.
 ie:

```
using namespace std;
class dummy{
public:
    int x;
    explicit dummy(int x = 0) : x{ this->x = x } {}; //explicit has no effect here
};

class myClass {
public:
    //operator int();
    explicit operator dummy();

};
/*
myClass::operator int() {
    return 10;
}*/

myClass::operator dummy(){
    return dummy(9);
}

int main() {
    myClass mc1; 
    dummy val = (dummy)mc1;
    //cout << "mc1 int cast: " << mc1 << endl; 
    cout << "val.x: " << val.x << endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

this will produce the following output (as expected):

```
val.x: 9
```

Edit: explicit keyword was missing in the second example. The output is the same

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that `clang-cl` (from withing VS 2019) has no problem with your *original* code.

Comment: what?? How do I change my compiler within visual studio. Im using vs 2017. I'm assuming it has to be some sort of bug in the compiler as opposed to an obscure c++ standard

Comment: Not sure how to get `clang` into VS2017 (but I believe it *can* be done). But, for VS2019, see [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/) - it may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling your original code with gcc-9 on ubuntu 18.04 I get this:

```
test.cpp:27:24: error: call of overloaded ‘dummy(myClass&)’ is ambiguous
   27 |     dummy val = (dummy)mc1;
      |                        ^~~
test.cpp:7:14: note: candidate: ‘dummy::dummy(int)’
    7 |     explicit dummy(int x = 0) : x{ this->x = x } {}; //explicit has no effect here
      |              ^~~~~
test.cpp:4:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr dummy::dummy(const dummy&)’
    4 | class dummy{
      |       ^~~~~
test.cpp:4:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr dummy::dummy(dummy&&)’
```

What is happening is the compiler cannot tell if you want to create a new 'dummy' class out of the int conversion of 'myClass' or a new 'dummy' out of the implicitly generated copy operator of 'dummy'.

This causes a loop where 'myClass' can be converted to both `int` and `dummy` which means that compiler gets stuck trying to convert 'myClass' since it doesnt know what you actually want to do - convert to 'dummy', convert to 'dummy' then copy it, or make a new 'dummy' by converting 'myClass' to `int`

The solution to this is to make your conversion operator to int `explicit` this prevents implicit conversion by the compiler and allows this to work (at least on gcc-9).

This is an updated copy of your code which will work:

```
using namespace std;
class dummy{
public:
    int x;
    explicit dummy(int x=0) : x(x) {}


};

class myClass {
public:
    explicit operator int(); // < Set to explicit
    explicit operator dummy();

};

myClass::operator int() {
    return 10;
}

myClass::operator dummy(){
    return dummy(9);
}

int main() {
    myClass mc1; 
    dummy val = static_cast<dummy>(mc1);
    cout << "mc1 int cast: " << static_cast<int>(mc1) << endl; 
    cout << "val.x: :" << val.x << endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles with gcc-9 and clang++-9

As a side note please please please never use C style casts in C++, they are error prone and a pain in the ass to debug

Comment: Does that not imply a class could only implement a single conversion? In other words, how could I tell when such an ambiguity occurs if there is any.

Comment: See my updated edit on implicit conversion and the explicit keyword. Bugs like this are the reason it is recommended practice to _always_ make conversion operators and conversion constructors explicit

Comment: many thanks! Although, it would be hard to remove my C habbits, I will try.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ambiguity between the way an object of the type `dummy` can be 
created.

The first one is when the `operator dummy` is called creating a temporary object of the type `dummy` and then the copy constructor is called due to the explicit cast conversion.

The second one is when the object of the type `myClass` is converted to the type `int` due to the `operator int` and then the conversion constructor of the class `myClass` is called to create an object of the type `dummy`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the two ways of creating an object of a class using the explicit casting.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    explicit A( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) { std::cout << "A( " << x << " )\n"; }
    A( const A & ) { std::cout << "A( const A & )\n"; }
    int x;
};

int main() 
{
    A a( 1 );

    std::cout << '\n';

    ( A )a;

    std::cout << '\n';

    ( A )2;


    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
A( 1 )

A( const A & )

A( 2 )
```

Relative to your program then in your program there is one additional step before using these ways: either an object of the type `myClass` will be preliminary converted to the type `dummy` or to the type `int`.

Comment: I see, do you advise to avoid using overloading with operator? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @SilverFlash You have to be caution when using the operator overloading to avoid ambiguity.